# Create Excel file from Python

Tags: python, excel

My project is to treat different Excel files. To do this, I would like to create a single file that contains some data of the previous files. All this in order to have my database. The goal is to obtain graphs of these data. All of this automatically.

I wrote this program in Python. However, it takes 20 minutes to run it. How can I optimize it?
In addition, I have identical variables in some files. So I would like that in the final file, the identical variables are not repeated. How to do?

Here is my program :

```
import os
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter
from xlrd import open_workbook

wc = xlrd.open_workbook("U:\\INSEE\\table-appartenance-geo-communes-16.xls")
sheet0=wc.sheet_by_index(0)

# création 

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('U:\\INSEE\\Department61.xlsx') as bdd:
    dept61 = bdd.add_worksheet('deprt61')

folder_path = "U:\\INSEE\\2013_telechargement2016"

col=8
constante3=0
lastCol=0
listeV = list()

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):   
    for filename in files:            
        filename = os.path.join(path, filename)        
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, '.xls')            
        sheet1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0)        
        lastRow=sheet1.nrows          
        lastCol=sheet1.ncols           
        colDep=None
        firstRow=None
        for ligne in range(0,lastRow):                  
            for col2 in range(0,lastCol):                     
                if sheet1.cell_value(ligne, col2) == 'DEP':
                    colDep=col2
                    firstRow=ligne
                    break
            if colDep is not None:
                break
        col=col-colDep-2-constante3
        constante3=0
        for nCol in range(colDep+2,lastCol):
                    constante=1
                    for ligne in range(firstRow,lastRow):
                            if sheet1.cell(ligne, colDep).value=='61':
                                    Q=(sheet1.cell(firstRow, nCol).value in listeV)
                                    if Q==False:
                                            V=sheet1.cell(firstRow, nCol).value
                                            listeV.append(V)
                                            dept61.write(0,col+nCol,sheet1.cell(firstRow, nCol).value)
                                            for ligne in range(ligne,lastRow):
                                                    if sheet1.cell(ligne, colDep).value=='61':
                                                            dept61.write(constante,col+nCol,sheet1.cell(ligne, nCol).value)
                                                    constante=constante+1

                                    elif Q==True:
                                            constante3=constante3+1 # I have a problem here. I would like to count the number of variables that already exists but I find huge numbers.
                    break
        col=col+lastCol   

bdd.close()
```

Thanks you for your future help. :)

Comment: imho, the entire code block after `for filename in files:` needs to be indented by 1 level, for the loops to make sense, except `bdd.close()`. I've made that edit. If that's wrong, edit again.

Answer (score 0):

This one may be too broad for SO, so here are some pointers for where you can optimise. Maybe add a sample screenshot of what the sheets look like.

1. Wrt `if sheet1.cell_value(ligne, col2) == 'DEP':` Can 'DEP' occur multiple times in a sheet? If it will definitely occur *only once* and that's when you get your values for both `colDep` and `firstRow`, then break out of both loops. Add `break` out of both loops, by adding a break to end the inner loop, then check for a flag value and break out of the outer loop before iterating over it. Like so:

   ```
   colDep = None    # initialise to None
   firstRow = None  # initialise to None
   for ligne in range(0,lastRow):                  
       for col2 in range(0,lastCol):                     
           if sheet1.cell_value(ligne, col2) == 'DEP':
               colDep=col2
               firstRow=ligne
               break    # break out of the `col2 in range(0,lastCol)` loop
       if colDep is not None:    # or just `if colDep:` if colDep will never be 0.
           break    # break out of the `ligne in range(0,lastRow)` loop
   ```
2. I think the range in `for ligne in range(0,lastRow):` in your write-to-bdd blocks should start at `firstRow` since you know that 0 to firstRow-1 will be empty in `sheet1` which you've just read to look for the header.

   ```
   for ligne in range(firstRow, lastRow):
   ```

   That will avoid wasting time reading empty header rows.

Other considerations for cleaner code:

- Use the [`with xlsxwriter.Workbook('U:\INSEE\\Department61.xlsx') as bdd:` syntax](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html) for clarity.

  - and always use double slashes `\\` inside strings even if not preceding a control character: `'U:\\INSEE\\Department61.xlsx'`
- You've used [`sheet1.cell_value()`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.cell_value) as well as [`sheet1.cell().value`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell) for your read operations. Pick one, unless you needed extended Cell info in the `value=='61'` case.
- Read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for how to write more readable code.

Comment: I changed some of my code. However, I have some problems.